# What were the reason behind the current offsides rules in football (soccer)? Also why have they been changed throughout its history?

Tags: rules, football, history

I know the [offside rule in football](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/14/527), but how did the current ruling come about? Along history, there have been numerous modifications to this particular rule.

Comment: @gbianchi Borderline...but I read the question as "What is the reason behind *today's* offside rule and its transformation over time?" vs. "Why introduce and keep offside if it creates controversy?" I think both are legitimate questions, but is the scope being covered the same?

Comment: Sorry, I read actually the same question.. maybe a better rephrase could fix this?

Comment: @gbianchi how could this be better rephrased? it's clear that the community thinks this is a possible duplicate, as you state.

Comment: guys, I did mean _today's_ offside rules, to the point of how have they changed over the course of the game's history, and the reasons behind the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What were the reason behind the current offsides rules in football (soccer)?

To reduce confusion<sub>[(1)](http://sportsillustrated.cnn.com/soccer/news/20130302/soccer-offside-rule-changed.ap/)</sub> for officials, players, and fans. As a result, the [International Football Association Board](http://www.fifa.com/aboutfifa/organisation/ifab/index.html) have now stated when attackers have influence during play.

> The change states that an attacker should be considered offside when "gaining an advantage by being in that position'' in situations that
>   will now include receiving the ball from a rebound or deflection from
>   the goal frame or a player in the defending team attempting a tackle,
>   block or save.

---

> Also why have they been changed throughout its history?

This [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offside_%28association_football%29#History) and this [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20111005003701/http://www.corshamref.org.uk/offhist.htm) covers the history of offside in football (soccer).

Several reasons include:

- Freeing up game flow
- Reducing confusion
- Reducing uncertainty of calls

  > If an assistant referee is not totally sure about an offside offence the flag should not be raised (i.e. in case of doubt benefit must be given to the attacking team).
- Ensuring correct judgment

  > an assistant referee should not raise the flag before considering the
  >   following criteria, so called "wait and see" technique:
  >
  > - Movement of the ball  (direction, speed, distance, any deflection, etc.)
  > - Involvement of the player in active play by interfering with play...an opponent or gaining an advantage.