# Offside Scenario with Goalkeeper in Other Half

Tags: football

Let's say the goalie (Team A) is way up the field (let's say for a corner kick late in the game)... He leaves one defender (Team A) parked on his 18 yard box... The opposing team wins the ball and starts a quick counter... the ball gets played up to the 2 forwards on team B who advance the ball past half field and find themselves in a 2 on 1 with the defender (team A) parked on the 18 box.

Let's say forward  # 1  passes the ball up to forward #2 who is not quite at the 18 where the defender is sitting.  Is this offside because there is only 1 defender? (goalie is too slow getting back)

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate of the linked duplicate.

Comment: Even though one could find the answer to this question in the provided link, this question is not a duplicate of it. Here we're talking about the relationship of goalie and an offside call (which for the record, offside has nothing to do with the position of the goalie).

Answer (score 5):

Yes. He is offside.

The offside rule is defined as a line created by the *second to last* defender. It doesn't matter who that is, if you're behind the second to last guy (and ahead of the ball, and past midfield) when the ball is passed, you're off sides.

A comprehensive answer is [here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-is-offside-determined-in-soccer)