# Position of the Defense in Soccer Offside

Tags: football, officiating

Trying to learn the Offside rule.  From what I gather Offside is when an offensive player gets behind the defense and takes a pass from another player. So, why doesn't the defense just stop around midfield so the offense can't take a pass past that point.  Just Curious!

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE. For reference, here is [How offside is determined in soccer](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-is-offside-determined-in-soccer?rq=1).

Comment: I'm a bit unsure about the close vote here. This is a good question about why the defence doesn't just keep a high line at all times.

Comment: As a comment on the question, you'll find that at lower levels of the game, the defence does try to push up and keep a very high line. The skill to play a ball past the defence that isn't collected by the goalkeeper can be very hard to master.

Answer (score 6):

Some parts of the rule that might contribute towards an answer for your question are:

An attacking player can't be offside in his own half, so a defence won't ever push up beyond the halfway line for the purpose of playing an offside trap.

Also the offside is determined when a pass is first played, so the higher a defence pushes up - the more space in behind them there is to drop a pass. Defences are particularly vulnerable to this against quick attackers.

A player is only offside if a pass is played towards the opposition goal(/forwards), so if a defence is pushed up high and an attacker dribbles past them he can pass backwards/sideways to a fellow attacker.

Thats just the basics. There's a lot more to the rule including some subjectivity. Link for more information: [The FA's Law 11: Offside](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thefa.com%2Ffootball-rules-governance%2Flaws%2Ffootball-11-11%2Flaw-11---offside.aspx&ei=ce1YVLauNczasAT9zYLIDg&usg=AFQjCNFGg1I5Dw5r-Yz9ngU2xxwYqVY-Bg&bvm=bv.78677474,d.eXY)

Answer (score 2):

### While holding a high defensive line can be an effective tactic, it can also be exploited.

A high defensive line leaves a lot of open space behind the defense for an attacking team to exploit. In order to take advantage of this space, the attacking team might use any number of tactics to bypass the defense without being ruled offside.

- Perhaps the most obvious method is for a fast attacking player to
  dribble past the defense and out-run them, potentially creating a
  one-on-one opportunity against the goalkeeper.
- Another method is for one player to pass/kick the ball beyond the
  defense, and for another player to run in behind the defense
  immediately after the ball is kicked.
- A third method is to take advantage of the fact that the offside rule
  doesn't apply when the ball is received directly from a throw-in or
  goal kick.

***NOTE:*** These methods can be optimized by finding open channels of space between defenders, giving the attacking player an advantage due to the angle, starting position and timing of their run.

These and other tactics can force defenders out of position, opening up new options for the attacking team. As a side-effect, defenders could become fatigued from covering a larger area of the field. If individual defenders don't respond as quickly as others, the defensive line could be compromised, exposing more space behind the defense.

Once the attacking team gets behind the defense, they can legally pass the ball horizontally or backward. As they approach the goal, any remaining defenders or the goalkeeper will have to choose a defensive position, potentially leaving other attacking players open to receive a pass and/or creating a goal-scoring opportunity.

**In summary**, a high defensive line can leave a team vulnerable. While it might be effective under certain circumstances, it is certainly not a tactical silver bullet.

Answer (score -1):

In short, the only time a player is offside is when the player is in front of everyone on the other team excluding the goalie, and then is attempted a pass to the offside player. This would result in a free kick for the defense. If a player just carries the ball past the defense, there is no offsides. What cancels an offsides is when the ball is also past the last defender. Therefore, if there are two offense in front of the whole other team, they can pass to each other and not be offsides.

Comment: Firstly, what is "offsides" (hint: it's not plural), secondly "the only time a player is offside is when the player is in front of everyone on the other team excluding the goalie" is definitely not true.

Comment: How is it untrue? And offsides is just the terminology that I was raised on while playing multiple levels of club, varsity, travel and indoor soccer. I have enough experience through refereeing and playing to know when a player is "offside". And I said when there is an attempt to pass the ball to a player that is ahead of the entire team with respect to the reference frame excluding the goalie. This reference frame where the goal the player who is offside is trying to score a goal in being the destination and the offside player is ahead of the other team. Which I know for a fact is true.

Comment: And the reason defenders don't stay on the high side is because the offense is usually capable of just dribbling past the defense, which leaves the goalie extremely vulnerable to being scored on.

Comment: Offside has nothing to do with the goalkeeper.

Comment: If the goalkeeper is out of his box, and is acting as another player on the field than yes, it does. I was simply just using his position as a marker for the other team'a relative position to the player who is offsides and the goalie. I feel as though you are over analyzing my comments and answer.

Comment: I'm not overanalysing - I'm pointing out information in the answer that is incorrect.

You said Offside is when the player is in front of everyone on the other team excluding the goalie and a pass is attempted. Both "in front of everyone on the other team excluding the goalie" and "pass is attempted" are incorrect.

Offside is when a player who was closer to their opponents' goal line than the second last defender when the ball was last played or touched by a teammate either: interferes with play, interferes with an opponent, or gains an advantage by being in that position.

Comment: And there is no offside from a throw-in, goal kick, corner kick, nor can you be in an offside position in your own half.

Comment: What do you mean by second to last defender? Are you including the keeper? Because if there is any defender closer to the goal line than the player on offense when the ball is passed forward, that is not offside.

Comment: Your last statement is true.

Comment: It's all true. Read Law 11 of the 2014/15 FIFA Laws of The Game.

Comment: But if there is only the keeper that is closer to the goal line than the player on offense when the ball is played forward or towards the goal line by a kick, that is offside.

Comment: You are correct. My line of phrasing was mistaken.

Comment: The only thing that you really need as part of your answer is "the reason defenders don't stay on the high side is because the offense is usually capable of just dribbling past the defense, which leaves the goalie extremely vulnerable to being scored on." The question isn't "what is offside?", but "why don't the defenders just keep a high line?".

Answer (score -2):

When someone is passing the ball to the forward and in that same moment he is the closest player to the goalkeeper. (He is behind the defenders). THat is offside in football.
I don't want to complicate so this is my short answer.
Hope you'll understand :)

Comment: That is not entirely correct.  You can be onside even behind the goalkeeper if there are two defending players between you and the goal.

Comment: If the ball is passed to someone behind you, you are not off side either.. this is not a good answer...

Comment: Or from a throw-in.  Or from a goal kick... etc.

Comment: I said behind the defending players, not behind the goalkeeper!

Comment: This is not how offside is judged, but that isn't the question anyway. The question is "why doesn't the defence just keep a high line?"

Comment: The question is asking why the defenders don't put players of the other team in offside, but you're trying to explain how offside works. Your answer is not relative.