# Is this an Offside according to FIFA rules?

Tags: rules, football, officiating

I was looking at fifa offside rules which are [here](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/afdeveloping/refereeing/law_11_offside_en_47383.pdf). In the slide/page 26 it explains about a **NO** offside scenario like this

[image]

Do I need to consider that direction of the pass which in this case is backwards (B2 passing backwards to C)

To be more clear is this allowed?

[image]

As you can see the passing direction is forward. If this is allowed (not offside) then I have another follow-up question

Comment: As clearly said, yes this is allowed. C appears to be leveled or slightly behind the ball, and thus can never be in an offside position.

Comment: Dupe or not? http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-is-offside-determined-in-soccer

Comment: @Don_Biglia: I don't think it is a duplicate. The other question is asking a very general question, and I think it is fine (maybe even better) to ask about specific aspects of the offside law too.

Comment: I was in doubt. But in the end even specific cases are going to refer to the general rules. I'm also starting to doubt if this is even a good question at all. He's asking if this is so according to Fifa rules while his images are in the fifa rules. The document he refers to is kind of the answer to his question and at the same time te source of his question. Feels like moving in circles or something like that :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From page 36 of the [2015/16 FIFA Laws of the Game](http://www.fifa.com/development/education-and-technical/referees/laws-of-the-game.html) (emphasis mine):

> A player is in an offside position if:
>
> - he is nearer to his opponents’ goal line than **both** the ball **and** the second-last opponent

In the first example provided in the question, player C is nearer to his opponents' goal line than the second-last opponent, **but not** the ball when the ball is last touched by a teammate. He is therefore not in an offside position and will not be penalised when he touches the ball.

In the second example provided in the question, in which player C is nearer to his opponents' goal than **both** the ball **and** the second-last opponent when the ball is last touched by a teammate (in the image provided by OP, player C is probably still just behind the ball even though I believe this is not what the original question intended). He is therefore in an offside position and will be penalised for interfering with play when he touches the ball.

Contrary to other answers (which since have been deleted), neither the direction that the ball is played nor where the player is standing when he touches the ball have any relevance on whether an offside offence has occurred.

Comment: Are you talking about the OP's examples?

Comment: @Don_Biglia - yes. I'll make an edit to ensure this is clearer.

Comment: Well then, C is not in an offside position, he is leveled with the ball. It's even said so: "No offside offence" is cleary in the example.

Comment: The second picture is just the first one edited by OP. The fact it says "no offside offence" bears no relevance. You may be right, the goalside edge of the ball is probably just ahead of the front edge of C's toe, but I don't believe this is what OP was trying to show. I will make this edit however.

Comment: As an aside, it's practically impossible for anyone to be level, given that the assistant referee should be comparing two infinitely thin lines across the field. The reason this is written into the laws is so that if they're so close that the AR can't tell, he rules the player onside.

Answer (score 8):

The problem with your second scenary is not the pass per se.. is the position of player C. if player C is behind the ball, there is no problem if the pass go foward or backward, since the ball in that case is the line that mark offside position.