# Offside or not?

Tags: rules, football

In a football match, a forward walks back in an offside position, but not included in any play. Ball gets played from the middle of the pitch, a defender heads it and it goes to the forward
1 - linesman puts flag up immediately, as the ball is played. Is that too early.
2 - The forward gets the ball, is he offside?

Comment: Might wanna take a look at this: https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/3/364

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is offside determined in soccer?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-is-offside-determined-in-soccer)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the situation. Assuming that defender tries to save the ball with their header the attacking player would still be in an illegal offside position.

[Law 11.2:](http://www.theifab.com/laws/offside/chapters/offside-offence)

> A player in an offside position at the moment the ball is played or
>   touched by a team-mate is only penalised on becoming involved in
>   active play by: (...)
>
> - gaining an advantage by playing the ball or interfering with an opponent when it has:
>
>   - rebounded or been deflected off the goalpost, crossbar, match
>       official or an opponent
>   - **been deliberately saved by any opponent**
> - A player in an offside position receiving the ball from an opponent who deliberately plays the ball (*except from a deliberate save by any
>     opponent*) is not considered to have gained an advantage.
>
> A ‘save’ is when a player stops, or attempts to stop, a ball which is
>   going into or very close to the goal with any part of the body except
>   the hands/arms (unless the goalkeeper within the penalty area).

If the defender was not just saving the ball (or trying to) the situation would be legal according to this part:

> *A player in an offside position receiving the ball from an opponent
>   who deliberately plays the ball (**except from a deliberate save by any
>   opponent**) is not considered to have gained an advantage.*