# Is it an offside in this case?

Tags: rules, football, officiating

When two players are facing the goalkeeper alone. and the first player passes the ball to the second and he scores.

notes:

- The moment when the ball was passed to the first player none of the two players are offside.
- when the first player passes the ball to the second player, the later is closer to the goal line than the ball.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is offside determined in soccer?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-is-offside-determined-in-soccer)

Comment: This is a particular case, I understand how offside is determined in general.

Comment: It would appear not, if the subsequent question is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's offside (unless there's an additional defender closer to the goal line, let's say in the vicinity of one of the corners. In such a case, the two players can still be said to be facing the goalkeeper alone, but it's rare and I assume you don't mean a situation like this).

> when the first player passes the ball to the second player, the later is closer to the goal line than the ball.

That's probably the key here; if the second player would be 'behind' the ball, (s)he wouldn't be offside. Now it's definitely a case of offside.

Comment: I always thought that the position of the player and the last two defenders (including the goalkeeper) are the only determinants of the offside. The fact that the position of the player and the ball matter is the new thing for me here. thanks for the clarification.