# Is Drop-kick allowed when free kick is awarded inside the box

Tags: rules, football, officiating, english-premier-league

On Sunday, in Liverpool vs United, on 93rd minute Mata was given offside, both the refs had given offside (they showed offside signs and ref whistles too). Alisson caught the ball and took a drop-kick (kicking the ball through his hands) which assisted Salah and resulted in the goal.

As per my knowledge, an **INDIRECT FREEKICK** is awarded for an offside. So how did Alisson take it as drop-kick and even after whistling and showing offside sign, how was he allowed to take it? (Ref did not show advantage).

[image]

So my question is, is drop-kick allowed for an offside if it is in the box?

Comment: Possibly related: https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/24550/15589

Comment: @F1Krazy I did not talk about Salah being offside. He wasn't. Salah's offside is not in the question.

Comment: That's why I said "related" and not "duplicate". It's about the same goal and claims the ball was in open play at the time. Maybe that question was wrong though.

Comment: Who decides if the ball is in open play or not? The keeper caught it and it's not about the goal here. it's about how the offside freekick was taken.

Comment: do you have a video source on whether the whistle was blown? If it was not, the goal is pefectly fine. Even if there was offside, the referee could have decided to let the game continue as possession turned over anyway.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. The Ref did not give an advantage signal but gave an offside signal and allowed it to continue. Why this?

Comment: NBC has this on their highlight reel.  https://youtu.be/Y4-NjhgsUSY?t=724

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whistle was **not** blown, at all.

Play was never stopped.

No player was penalised for offside.

There was never a free kick.

Alisson played the ball legally to Salah in the same way he and every other goalkeeper does regularly.