# Soccer Offsides

Tags: rules, football, officiating

[image]I have a question about offsides like in the picture below. Let's say 2 offensive players are in a 2 vs 1 against goalkeeper... they already beat last defender. The offensive player then passes the ball to his teammate while both are in front of goalkeeper. Is it offsides when the player receives the ball?

Comment: Why do you think this might possibly _not_ be offside? In particular, see [How is offside determined in football?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-is-offside-determined-in-football)

Comment: If you believe the linked duplicate _doesn't_ answer your question, please [edit your question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/28752/edit) to explain the exact issue rather than asking in comments. Thanks!